# Using GPars to process nodes in a tree with caching of the processed nodes

Tags: gpars

I am processing a tree, and would like to speed it up using GPARs.  I've used it for simple things but haven't delved into the more complex options.

Assume that I am processing different branches of the tree with their own threads.

Let's say a node has a name.  When I hit that node the first time, I want it to be processed (which involves writing things to a database, etc.), and added to a cache (just a simple map here).

I want other threads that may hit that same node (e.g. a node with the same name) elsewhere on the tree, to check the cache. If it's already in the cache, they can just grab it and move on.  If another thread is working on processing that node for the first time, I want the other threads that are on that node in their branches to wait before going on down the tree (to other things that depend on that node having already been processed).

The node is pulled from the db, so it's not the same object in each branch, I don't think synchronized methods will work.

I of course want other unrelated nodes to continue to be processed.

For example:

- Thread 1 is processing A-B-C-D
- Thread 2 is processing E-B-F-G
- Thread 3 is processing W-X-Y
- Thread 4 is processing L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-B-J

Let's say Thread 1 gets to node B first.  It finds it's not in the cache, so it begins to process it.

Thread 2 comes along and sees node B is not in the cache, but it's being worked on.  So it waits to go on to node F until Thread 1 is done processing node B.

Thread 3 doesn't care about node B and so keeps cranking along.

Thread 4 comes along later after Thread 1 has finished with node B and finds node B in the cache, so it just pulls it from the cache and continues on to node J.

I am looking for suggestions of how I could best apply GPARs to this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought would be to use a shared ConcurrentHashmap with node names as keys and DataflowVariables as values.

Threads use putIfAbsent(nodename, new DataflowVariable()) to atomically insert a promise for processed node's data and if the operation suceeds the thread may start processing the node and eventually bind the result to the DataflowVariable.

If putIfAbsent() fails, some other thread has already started processing a node with the same name. In that case the current thread may just grab the DataflowVarieble associated with the node name and wait for the result to be available - either calling get() or whenBound().

Comment: So for Thread 4 above, should it do a get() on the hashmap first, then do a putIfAbsent()?  Or should every thread always do a putIfAbsent, then if the item was processed long ago, the DataFlowVariable will always return from get() quickly?  Incidentally I can't vote up your answer (I tried) b/c I don't have reputation 15 yet ;-)

Comment: And a stupid question - I am iterating using eachParallel, can I simply use the DataFlowVariable directly, or do I need to be using DataFlow tasks?  Thanks!

Comment: You may or may not call get() ahead of putIfAbsent(). It may save some processing time by avoiding building DataflowVariables that will never be used, provided the probability of get() returning a non-null is high. If get() returns null, however, no asumptions should be made and putIfAbsent() must follow, since it is the putIfAbsent() that guarantees atomicity.

Comment: Once a value has been bound to a DataflowVariable, it will always return that value instantly through the its get() method.

Comment: DataflowVariables can be used from any threads irrespective of whether they have been started as plain Java threads, pooled threads, GPars tasks or parallel collection mathods, such as eachParallel.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I really like GPARs (we use the basic *parallel methods a lot), but documentation-wise it seems to assume you already understand some things about parallelism.  I need the beginner's guide.  Examples: I had no idea which of the many strategies to apply here.  Also, when looking at Dataflow, what does .join() do?  Anyway, thanks a ton for your help, and the various articles and such you've supplied on the web.

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks for the feedback. I agree that the documentation leaves quite a lot to desire and I believe it'll get better as we move forward.